# How to attach multiple partitions in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Used below query to attach one partition in ClickHouse.

`alter table a_status_2 attach partition '20210114' from a_status_1;`

How to attach multiple partitions in ClickHouse?

Answer (score 1):

> How to attach multiple partitions in ClickHouse?

No way to do it automatically.

You can generate SQL script using system.detached_parts

```
select concat('alter table `',table, '` attach part id '||partition_id||';')
from system.detached_parts
where database = 'xxx' and table = 'yyy'
```

Or https://gist.github.com/den-crane/5ae44ec04961ec62286835c8798e2728

```
let i=1;for f in `ls -1` ; do echo $i $f;((i++)); echo "alter table A.d attach part '$f';"|clickhouse-client ; done
```